# Why doesn't xsl:sort work when using xsl:key?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <chapter-section-datasource>
        <section id="12" handle="chapter-section">Chapter Section</section>
        <entry id="94">
            <order handle="1">1</order>
        </entry>
    </chapter-section-datasource>
    <page-content>
        <section id="9" handle="page-content">x</section>
        <chapter-section link-id="94">
            <entry id="87">
                <section-id>0</section-id>
            </entry>
            <entry id="91">
                <section-id>2</section-id>
            </entry>
            <entry id="93">
                <section-id>1</section-id>
            </entry>
            <entry id="103">
                <section-id>3</section-id>
            </entry>
        </chapter-section>
    </page-content>
</data>
```

And this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter-section-datasource/entry[1]" mode="bal"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Map Results -->
  <xsl:key name="guide" match="chapter-section" use="@link-id" />

  <xsl:template match="entry" mode="bal">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('guide', @id)" mode="balGuide">
      <xsl:sort select="section-id" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter-section/entry" mode="balGuide">
    <xsl:element name="div">
          <xsl:value-of select="section-id"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output is: **0,1,2,3**

The actual output is: **0,2,1,3**

Why isn't sort working as I expect? Note that the complexity of the transform is due the more complex XML and XSL which has been simplified for this example.

If it matters, the transformation is done in C#

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("Xml/simple.xml"));
System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform trans = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
trans.Load(Server.MapPath("Xml/simple.xsl"));
Xml1.Document = doc;
Xml1.Transform = trans;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
  <xsl:template match="entry" mode="bal">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('guide', @id)/entry" mode="balGuide">
      <xsl:sort select="section-id" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```

that is, you need to make sure you process and sort the `entry` elements (and not the sole parent where then no sorting happens and the default template kicks in to process the `entry` elements in the original order).

Here is a full stylesheet, also changed the `order="ascending"` as you say you want `0,1,2,3`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter-section-datasource/entry[1]" mode="bal"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Map Results -->
  <xsl:key name="guide" match="chapter-section" use="@link-id" />

  <xsl:template match="entry" mode="bal">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('guide', @id)/entry" mode="balGuide">
      <xsl:sort select="section-id" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter-section/entry" mode="balGuide">
    <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="section-id"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```